# Project suggestions for asp.net and ajax.net beginner

Tags: asp.net-ajax

I am a final year student doing BE in Software Engineering.
I just wanted to do my minor project in asp.net also using ajax.net. 
Would you suggest some feasible projects?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Choose something that is of interest to you or solves a real world problem you have. It's the best way to be really motivated to work on it...

Answer (score 0):

Library loan or airline booking system

Answer (score 0):

I would probably suggest working on a simple Asp.net project like Library managment system or a simple shopping cart etc.

First implement them in asp.net, Javascript.

Once you get good understanding of these two technologies, then start learning Jquery. The next step will be Ajax.

Even I was a BE final year student in 2007 went through the process and now working on Ajax.